# Finding max of a function without Calculus

Tags: functions

I have looked at previous problem I posted, and I can see I made typo in my original for which I sorry of.

I meant to write.

$T(x) = 45 \cdot  0.9541^{x^2-20 \cdot x}$ where $x \geq 0$

But is it still same approach? That I have to minimize $x^2-20 \cdot x$ ?

I try to solve $x^2-20 \cdot x = 0 $ and get $ x = 0 $ $\land$  $x = 20$ and then divide $x = 20$ by two then I get the maximum place $x = 10$ (do to symmetry).

Is that a recommended approach?

Comment: That works for this problem. In general, the x coordinate of the vertex of a parabola $a \, x^2 + b \, x + c$ is $-b/(2a)$, which in this problem is $20/2 = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The reason it works is that $y=a\cdot b^x$ is a monotonically increasing (for $b>1$) one-to-one function.  So if $f(x)$ is that function, and $g(x)$ is the parabola, the derivative $$[f\circ g(x)]' = [f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$ so the combined function will have zero slopes at the same $x$ values that $g(x)$ does.